# How to get url from text file?

Tags: c#, winforms, url, webbrowser-control, filestream

i have inserted some web URL's in a text file.

Like:

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.twitter.com
www.yahoo.com
```

And I want to browse web page URL form text file in c# webBrowse1 control.

please tell me how it works.

This is my code but it didn't work.

```
try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("link.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(sr);
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Internet Connection not found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Help yourself enormously: never _eat_ exceptions. You're catching all exceptions and then displaying a message box _containing no information about the exception_. Be certain that you display `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the main problem I see is you're trying to navigate to a stream:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
webBrowser1.Navigate(sr); //<-- This doesn't make any sense!
```

What you probably want to do is loop through the text file and read each line:

```
foreach(string url in File.ReadLines("link.txt"))
{
   webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

   // Do stuff here with your webBrowser1 control
}
```

This will loop through each line in link.txt and call `Navigate()` on each one.  I'm not quite sure if that's what you want, so please clarify if there's more to this problem.

Comment: it worked well (foreach(string sr in File.ReadAllLines("link.txt"))
{
   webBrowser1.Navigate(sr);
})
now can you tell me how can i use different proxy for each link using poxylist.txt

Comment: @user1576034 - It's best to focus on a single issue per post so the site stays searchable and organized.  I would recommend you post a new question with details about your proxy issue.